# HC-SR04 gets stuck (Python and Raspberry Pi)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to use the HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Python. I got the majority the code from [this site](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/hc-sr04-ultrasonic-range-sensor-on-the-raspberry-pi). However, When I reduce the sleep time between each measurement of distance, The code gets stuck in the `while GPIO.input(ECHO)==0:` loop and then that stops everything. Maybe I'm setting the sleep time too low, But I really don't see how that would change anything.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
TRIG=23
ECHO=24

GPIO.setup(TRIG,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO,GPIO.IN)

def pulseIn():
    while True:
        GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
        time.sleep(.000005)
        GPIO.output(TRIG, True) # Sending out a trigger pulse for 10 microseconds
        time.sleep(.00001)
        GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
        pulse_start = time.time()
        pulse_end = time.time()
        while GPIO.input(ECHO)==0: # This is where it keeps getting stuck
            pulse_start = time.time()
            #if pulse_start-pulse_end>.5:  # This is one of my attempts to fix the problem.
            # It caused some bad output values
             #   continue

        while GPIO.input(ECHO)==1:
            pulse_end = time.time()
        return pulse_end-pulse_start


time.sleep(2) # Giving the sensor some time to warm up
for i in range(100):
    print(pulseIn()*17500)
    time.sleep(.001) # It seems to work when I set this to 1, but I would prefer if it worked faster
```

Answer (score 2):

Raspberry pi, unlike Arduino or other microcontroller platform, is a computer based on a Microprocessor and therefore has an operating system running on it to control software/hardware aspects of its operation. Multitasking Operating systems have schedulers that essentially provides all running processes, a chunk of hardware(cpu) to process instructions.

The caveat that comes with this is that, an instruction may not be executed immediately if the scheduler gives priority to other processes.

The following chunk of code would likely cause issues since getting the pulse is a time sensitive operation.

```
while GPIO.input(ECHO)==0:
        pulse_start = time.time()

while GPIO.input(ECHO)==1:
        pulse_end = time.time()

return pulse_end-pulse_start
```

Your loop would likely run infinitely if the sensor is done sending the low pulse and process start reading it then.
You could also get wildly incorrect values attributing to such delays.

**So, what's the solution ?**

If I were you, I would use a microcontroller to read the values from the sensor and then read the recorded data from it using I2c or any other communication protocol supported.

However you could also add a counter in your while loops to handle such cases like it is described here:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82833/hc-sr04-randomly-stops-taking-readings

Answer (score 1):

From the datasheet we can see that this sensor has a maximum distance range of 4 meters. Hence, as you decrease the delay between two consecutive measurements, you might be sending another ultrasonic signal from the sensor when the previous signal has not arrived. Datasheet recommends 60 ms measurement cycle for this sensor. Your measurement cycle is much smaller than the recommended value.

Sensor datasheet:
https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Proximity/HCSR04.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with hc-src04. It stops working somehow. You should create another counter inside while loop. And then you should check that time to break inner while loop. Here is how I do it.

```
def distance(myStartingTime):
    
    calculation_starting_time = time.time()
    
    GPIO.output(trigger_pin,True)
    
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    
    GPIO.output(trigger_pin, False)
    
    start = time.time()
    end = time.time()
    
    while GPIO.input(echo_pin) == 0:
        
        calculation_starting_time = time.time()
        if calculation_starting_time - myStartingTime > 1:
            break
        start = time.time()
        
    while GPIO.input(echo_pin) == 1:
        
        calculation_starting_time = time.time()
        if calculation_starting_time - myStartingTime > 1:
            break
        
        end = time.time()
        
    difference = end-start
    distance = (difference*34300)/2
    return distance

while True:
    start = time.time()
    my_distance = distance(start)
    
    print("dist: ", my_distance)
```